# Regex to return set of words from file that can be spelled with letters passed as parameter (python)

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of words such as

```
name
age
abhor
apple
ape
```

I want to do regex on a list by passing a random set of letters  such as 'apbecd'

Now all those words from the list having the set of letters must be returned.

eg: `python retun_words.py apbelcdg`

will return

```
ape
apple
age
```

As of now, i am able to return words based only on words match. How can I achieve the results as I have mentioned above.
also if there is any other way to achieve the results instead of regex kindly let me know

Thanks in advance

Comment: `[word for word in words if re.match('[apbecd]*$', word)]`

Comment: Why abhor is not printed?

Comment: Ok. Since not all the characters of the word are from the character list?

Comment: abhor is not printed because 'hor' is not present in set of letters passed as parameter

Comment: Hi Rawing. your solution works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, using set and returning the item is also a way, if you do not want to use regex.

```
string_list = ["name", "age", "abhor", "apple", "ape"]
allowed_characters = "apbelcdg"
character_set = set(allowed_charcters)
print [item for item in string_list if not set(item)-character_set]
```

This will give you the list of strings that adhere to the character set.

However, if regex is what you desire the most, here we go :-)

```
from re import match
string_list = ["name", "age", "abhor", "apple", "ape"]
allowed_characters = "apbelcdg"
print [item for item in string_list if match('[%s]*$' % (allowed_characters), item)]
```

Comment: Hi thiruvenkadam, If I am trying to pick the words only with letter 'a', the code is not giving any results even though 'a' is present in list. however if i am trying other characters such as 'b' or 'c' its giving the results. 'a' is the very first character in the file. Can you please check as why your code is behaving like this? I assume it is ignoring the very first line from the file

Comment: Can you give the input you gave? I will check whether there is any bug :-)

Comment: It seems , there is a bug while reading the file. its not picking up the first line.
`def read_file(filename):
 try:
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
   contents = f.read(1)
   if not contents:
    print "File is empty!"
    sys.exit()
   else:
    lines = f.readlines()
    string_list = [line.strip() for line in lines]
    return string_list
 except IOError:  # FileNotFoundError
  print "File not found: {}".format(filename)
  sys.exit()`

Comment: That is because you are doing double read operation. With f.read(1), you already read one character. In the else, you right away do f.readlines(), which will start after the first character. Adding `lines = contents; lines += f.readlines()` will solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe shellmode's method needs a minor fix, since it would not work for cases when the examined letter is the same as the last letter in the word, but the word itself contains letters that are not from the letter list. I believe that this code would work:

```
import sys
word_list = ['name', 'age', 'abhor', 'apple', 'ape']
letter_list = sys.argv[1]

for word in word_list:
    for counter,letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter not in letter_list:
            break
        if counter == len(word)-1: #reached the end of word
            print word
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use regex. Following code works.

```
import sys
word_list = ['name', 'age', 'abhor', 'apple', 'ape']
letter_list = sys.argv[1]

for word in word_list:
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in letter_list:
            break
        elif letter == word[-1]:
            print word
```

Output

```
[root@mbp:~]# python return_words.py apbelcdg
age
apple
ape
```

Comment: Thanks Shellmode. I will evaluate both the ways and find out which is more fast

Comment: What's your arguments and word_list?

Comment: word list i am reading from a file. and argument list is 'apbelcdg'

Comment: Its throwing all words even if one letter is present in the letter_list

Comment: You should confirm that word_list must be a Python list data type

Comment: `import sys
word_list = map(str.strip, open('words.txt'))
letter_list = sys.argv[1]
for word in word_list:
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in letter_list:
            break
        elif letter == word[-1]:
            print word`

Comment: >>> word_list = map(str.strip, open('words.txt'))
>>> type(word_list)
<type 'list'>

Comment: `elif letter == word[-1]` does not do what you want. What if the last letter of the word also occures earlier in the same word? I.e. `foo`'s last letter is `o` , first iteration is `f`, 2nd iteration is `o`, `letter ==word[-1]` is therefore `True` and `foo` is printed. This is why loops can have an `else` clause in python, look it up.